# ChartJS not displaying properly in AJAX called page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, charts

I am using the latest version of chart JS (2.5.0) and trying to get 2 polar area charts to appear in a page that has the content of the page loaded in VIA ajax. Here are my two polar charts (I will omit the rest of the code as it is not pertinent to this):

```
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'polarArea',
  options: {
     responsive: true
  }
  data: {
    labels: ["Head", "Chest", "Stomach", "Left Arm", "Right Arm", "Left Leg", "Right Leg"],
    datasets: [{
      backgroundColor: [
        "#1AFF05",
        "#0D9900",
        "#197011",
        "#1E4A1A",
        "#4C4D4C",
        "#81917F",
        "#B5F7B0"
      ],
        data: <?php getHitBoxPercents($player);?>
      // data: [12, 19, 3, 17, 28, 24, 7]
    }]
  }
});
</script>
```

And Chart 2:

```
<canvas id="myChart1v1"></canvas>
 <script>
    var ctx1v1 = document.getElementById("myChart1v1").getContext('2d');
    var myChart1 = new Chart(ctx1v1, {
        type: 'polarArea',
        options: {
           responsive: true
        }
        data: {
        labels: ["Head", "Chest", "Stomach", "Left Arm", "Right Arm", "Left Leg", "Right Leg"],
        datasets: [{
          backgroundColor: [
            "#1AFF05",
            "#0D9900",
            "#197011",
            "#1E4A1A",
            "#4C4D4C",
            "#81917F",
            "#B5F7B0"
           ],
           data: <?php getHitBoxPercents($player);?>
           // data: [12, 19, 3, 17, 28, 24, 7]
        }]
      }
    });
  </script>
```

These are both in Tab menus which all works fine but here are the weird things:

- The first chart doesn't load properly at all, it loads the "outline" of the chart but no data, although the data is all set properly in the javascript and it works just fine if I take away the second chart. See picture: [Puush Image](http://puu.sh/w08r0/9528309a10.png)
- The chart from the second bit of code works perfectly: [Puush Image 2](http://puu.sh/w08uC/57e990fb86.png)
- If I press the button to generate the ajax again (a form with a search button to find matching records) The first chart goes away completely (code is all still there) and the second chart still works just fine. [Puush example of this](http://puu.sh/w08zs/1249b8f6cd.png)
- Maybe the key to this whole thing: If I resize the page the chart appears, regardless of if I reload the ajax in the page and the chart all disappears all I have to do is resize the page (go to half size then maximize again) and it works, both charts. I don't know why or how to fix this but I don't want that to be the only solution.

**EDIT:** I am trying to fix mine according to this fiddle but it isn't working: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/291w2jLk/) The new code I am trying to use:

```
 $(function(){

  var chart_polar_options = {
    responsive: true
  };

  var data1v1 = {
    labels: ["Head", "Chest", "Stomach", "Left Arm", "Right Arm", "Left Leg", "Right Leg"],
    datasets: [{
      backgroundColor: [
        "#1AFF05",
        "#0D9900",
        "#197011",
        "#1E4A1A",
        "#4C4D4C",
        "#81917F",
        "#B5F7B0"
      ],
        data: <?php getHitBoxPercents($player);?>
    }]
  };



    var ctx1v1 = document.getElementById("myChart1v1").getContext('2d');
    var myChart1 = new Chart(ctx1v1, {
      type: 'polarArea',
      options: {
        responsive: true
      },
      data: data1v1
    });
    $('#tab2').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
      myChart1.destroy();
      myChart1 = new Chart(ctx1v1, {
        type: 'polarArea',
        options: {
          responsive: true
        },
        data: data1v1
      });
    });

    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'polarArea',
      options: {
        responsive: true
      },
      data: data1v1
    });
    $('#tab1').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
      myChart.destroy();
      myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'polarArea',
        options: {
          responsive: true
        },
        data: data1v1
      });
    });
});
```

The problem with the code above is neither load until I resize the browser but it is pulling in the charts, they just look blank.

Comment: what happens if you hardcode the data? will it then show up?

Comment: Nothing changes, same problems occur, the first chart only loads outline while the second works, if I load in the ajax again the first outline disappears and the second chart loads fine. I added a bit more info on another weird bug I remembered. Resizing the page fixes it as in both charts load, but I don't want that to really be the solution as it isn't very elegant and is not practical.

Comment: You mention AJAX but there's no AJAX in the code ..... ??

Comment: I left the Ajax out because it all works, it sends the data, queries the database with the constraints passed and returns everything. That's all working, I omitted it to keep it as easy to read as possible.